# Object behavior in C#

Tags: c#

I have created two objects, `str` and `prog`. When I print both the objects

Output for Object 1: (The string is printed)

```
Web World!!
```

Output for Object 2: (The name of the Class is printed)

```
Program1
```

Can someone please explain why is this happening?

```
using System;
using System.Text;


public class Program1
{
    string str1;
    public Program1(string str2)
    {
        str1 = str2;
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Web World!!", 30);
        Console.WriteLine(str);

        Program1 prog = new Program1("Hello");
        Console.WriteLine(prog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you the System does not know how it should print an object of type Program1, the way to tell the System how to print that type is to override the ToString method in the Program1 class.
You can do this by simply adding:

```
public override string ToString() 
{
  return str1;
}
```

into the Program1 class. All C# objects naturally have this method but it will just return the class name (or some other value im not 100% sure) by default, we override this method to tell the System how to format an object of type Program1 as a string, allowing it to be printed correctly.

Comment: Thanks mate, that worked :)                                                                                                  
Just an additional question : where I can see these methods defined for inbuilt classes like StringBuilder?                                                                               
I cannot find the code anywhere

Comment: You can see it here: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StringBuilder.cs,336

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine(prog);` prints `Program1` because

> Every class or struct in C# implicitly inherits the Object class. Therefore, every object in C# gets the ToString method, which returns a string representation of that object.
> *(From [How to override the ToString method (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method))*

and

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type.
> *(From reference for [Object.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring))*

Here's an example of a class overriding `ToString` (from the first article)

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
    }
}
```

## Record types

It may be worth to mention record types.

From [Records (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record):

> Record types have a compiler-generated ToString method that displays the names and values of public properties and fields. The ToString method returns a string of the following format:
>
> ```
>  <record type name> { <property name> = <value>, <property name> = <value>, ...}
> ```

### Example

If `Program1` becomes a record, and `str1` becomes a property rather than a field

```
public record Program1
{
    public string Str1 { get; set; }
    public Program1(string str1)
    {
        Str1 = str1;
    }
}
```

then

```
Program1 prog = new Program1("Hello");
Console.WriteLine(prog);
```

prints

```
Program1 { Str1 = Hello }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling Console.WriteLine(someArg); and someArg is not string, ToString() method will be called automatically.

As @tymtam pointed

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type.

Your Program1 class inherits from object and do not override ToString(), so you are getting fully qualified name.

[StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0#methods) overrides ToString method which converting its value to string and you are getting "Web World!!" string